# How to insert 2 digit number in database after preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-4, preg-match-all

```
preg_match_all('#(\d[wW]+|\d[dD]+|\d[hH]+|\s+)#i', $category, $matches); $hours=0;  $days=0;

    $hoursss=0;
    foreach($matches[0] AS $match) {
        switch(true) {
            case preg_match('/\d[hH]+|\s+/', $match) :


                $hours +=(int)$match;
                break;

            case preg_match('/\d[dD]+|\s+/', $match) :
                $days +=(int)$match*24;
                break;

            case preg_match('/\d[wW]+|s+/', $match) :
                $hoursss+= (int)$match*24*7;
                break;
        }
        $case=$hours+$hoursss+$days;
    }
```

When I am giving input 2d2w2h,it is getting converted into total hours and get inserted into database.

But when i am giving input20w20d20h it is giving 0 in database .

Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first regex is wrong (match multiple digits in front of period letter), it should be:

```
#(\d+[wW]+|\d+[dD]+|\d+[hH]+|\s+)#i'
```

Also check other regular expressions for some edge cases, because the way you process it all is not flawless.